# How to track method calling in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to keep track what all action methods and methods written in model class are getting during execution of project as well as what is the execution time of that particular method(action method / method called in model class)

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: **Custom Filters**

Here is one example of Custom Filter that I have implemented to log/track all the activity - like which action methods are getting executed, at what time they are getting executed.

Basically, I have created a Custom Filter attribute - "TrackExecutionTime". I have implemented this for Action, Result and even Exception filters. I hope you are looking for something like this --

Custom Filter code -- TrackExecutionTime.cs

```
public class TrackExecutionTime : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string message = "\n" + filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName +
            " --> " + filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName + " --> OnActionExecuting \t - " +
            DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
        LogExecutionTime(message);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string message = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName +
            " --> " + filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName + " --> OnActionExecuted \t - " +
            DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
        LogExecutionTime(message);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string message = "\n" + filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() + 
            " --> " + filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() + " --> OnResultExecuting \t - " +
            DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
        LogExecutionTime(message);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string message = "\n" + filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() +
            " --> " + filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() + " --> OnResultExecuted \t - " +
            DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
        LogExecutionTime(message);
        LogExecutionTime("--------------------------------------------");
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        string message = "\n" + filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() +
            " --> " + filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() + " --> " + filterContext.Exception.Message + " \t - " +
            DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
        LogExecutionTime(message);
        LogExecutionTime("--------------------------------------------");
    }

    private void LogExecutionTime(string data)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/Data.txt"), data);
    }
}
```

Controller code where I have used this Custom Filter attribute --

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [TrackExecutionTime]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [TrackExecutionTime]
    public string Welcome()
    {
        throw new Exception("new exception is occured.");
    }
}
```

Logged data after Action methods executed --

```
Home --> Index --> OnActionExecuting     - 4/8/2017 4:21:57 PM
Home --> Index --> OnActionExecuted      - 4/8/2017 4:21:58 PM

Home --> Index --> OnResultExecuting     - 4/8/2017 4:21:58 PM

Home --> Index --> OnResultExecuted      - 4/8/2017 4:21:58 PM
--------------------------------------------
Home --> Welcome --> OnActionExecuting   - 4/8/2017 4:22:21 PM
Home --> Welcome --> OnActionExecuted    - 4/8/2017 4:22:21 PM

Home --> Welcome --> new exception is occured.   - 4/8/2017 4:22:21 PM
--------------------------------------------
```

I have successfully implemented this thanks to the resource:

```
    http://www.pragimtech.com/mvc-video-tutorial-for-beginners.aspx
```

Hope this is helpful. If it helps you solve your problem then don't forget to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is helpful to me. But using this we can only log information of actions o. Controller. But we cannot log information of model. Which model is getting called,execution time etc.. Is there any solution for that?